# How would I correctly format this SQL request?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql statement in my code:

```sql
SELECT country, count(*) as hits WHERE website=? from a GROUP BY country ORDER BY hits DESC
```

When I run this, it seems to fail. What is wrong with this? Where should I place the WHERE statement?

Comment: `SELECT x FROM y WHERE z` The rest is correct, the _from_ goes before the _where_. [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) for the complete reference for a _select_ query.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The order of clause is fixed in SQL.  For the ones you are using:

- `SELECT`
- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `ORDER BY`

This is the language.  So you want:

```
SELECT country, count(*) as hits 
FROM a
WHERE website = ? 
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT country, count(*) as hits 
  FROM a  
  WHERE website=? 
  GROUP BY country 
  ORDER BY hits DESC
```

This query will work after providing Where filter condition